# How does it improve the book to show the major's power?

Tags: scandinavian-languages, sophies-world, jostein-gaarder

In *Sophie's World*, as the end of the book approaches, crazier and crazier things begin to happen - dramatic storms, fairy tale characters in the forest, geese that carry people around, [strange garden parties](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3189/why-is-it-important-that-nowadays-its-the-girl-who-takes-the-initiative), and so forth. The purpose seems to be that it shows the power the author (well, not really the author, the in-book author, the major) has over the world.

But why is this shown through such fantastic events? I can understand inserting some irony ("breaking the fourth wall" so to speak) and lots of birthday references, but the fairy tale characters for the most part seem kind of random, and the whole party is just weird (though Alberto does suspect the crashing of the white Mercedes distracted the major so they could escape).

What was the purpose in making the ending so fantastic and wildly different from the rest of the book?